# Infopath form loading error

Tags: sharepoint, office365, infopath

we have migrated a site from sharepoint 2010 to office365. I had a infopath form previously now the form in office365 is giving me a loading error.Can anyone help me thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I wish there were more details about the errors, but try clearing cookies and see if it's related. Sometimes clearing cookies helps in similar situations on Office365

Answer (score 0):

What is the error you are getting? I know our issue was in a SP List where we had a dropdown item that was still pointing to the old SP and a rule on form load to query this old SP List and wouldnt open. I had to create a Find and replace powershell command to overcome this. If this sounds the same as what you are finding let me know and I will respond with a detailed how to!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for response @Ray and @kwagenknight.I have take an old template from old site changed data connections to new site and republished the form again.Now it works.